# Django if image is empty

Tags: django, django-forms

I created an article creation form. There is also have image upload button.

I used Pillow for resize to uploaded image. But when I say Save form without upload image take this error;

**forms.py in clean_image, line 19**
**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'**

There is no problem when I save the article with the image. But I can't save without image.

how do I say, if don't upload any picture "skip this section **"(def clean_image (self):)"**?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from PIL import Image
import hashlib
import io

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["title", "content","image"]

    def clean_image(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        md5.update(repr(image.name).encode('utf-8')) **#19.line is here!!!**
        file_name = md5.hexdigest()

        if image.size > 30 * 1024 * 1024:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File is too big.'), code='invalid')

        image = Image.open(image)

        if image.size[0] < 600 or image.size[1] < 600:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Your image needs to be at least 600x600.'))

        if image.format not in ('BMP', 'PNG', 'JPEG', 'GIF'):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Unsupported image type. Please uplod a bmp, png, jpeg, or gif."),
                                        code='invalid')

        image.thumbnail([1024, 1024], Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image_io = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(image_io, format=image.format)
        image_name = '{}.{}'.format(file_name, image.format)
        image = ContentFile(image_io.getvalue(), image_name)

        return image
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the field is empty before processing the image:

```
def clean_image(self):
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
    if image:
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        # ... the rest of the image processing stuff goes here...
    return image
```

Comment: thank you so much. my problem is solved. and sorry im beginner django :) thanks again... your best!